# Getting problems to Set Icons(Image) on HighCharts

Tags: javascript, api, highcharts, xhtml

I'm getting some troubles to set icons on my series over,infront,top,bot (anywhere) it.
I'm using an API (`agromonitoring.com`)  to get the Data with XHTML request parsing it to JSON then showing using Highcharts, the main problem is that most of the examples to add Icons or Images are using xAxis Categorized, but in my case I'm using an xAxis "date-time" which is always changing that's why I can't use this example (`https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-symbols`) of course I tried,but it doesn't work.

So Here it's the Example of Highcharts 
`https://codepen.io/pen/?editors=0010` 
and this is my example(both sites same)
`https://playcode.io/447786` (love PlayCode couse integrates console)
`https://jsfiddle.net/Miguel5tuxD/afgrzLv7/`
I'm trying to useiconUrl getting from that Switch to then parse around 40 icons to the Highchart

Expecting something like the example but with all points an Icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't set icons URL for point markers anywhere. So the solution is to pass points array like that (spline series):

```
[{
  x: x,
  y: y,
  marker: {
    symbol: url
  }
}, ...]
```

In your example:

```
{
  name: 'Temperatura',
  type: 'spline',
  data: datos3.map((item, index) => {
    return {
      x: item[0],
      y: item[1],
      marker: {
        symbol: datos[index],
        width: 20,
        height: 20
      }
    }
  }),
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ' °C',
    valueDecimals: 2,
  },
  marker: {
    enabled: true
  },
  color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2],
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/c81qz5vr/

Comment: WoW , thanks friend amazing help I was trying another things but you really help me alot of thanks for all :)